# How to calculate the cumulative sum for a vector of doubles in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, cumulative-sum

I have a vector of doubles and I need to create another array which is a cumulative sum of the elements of the first. For example;

```
 vector<double> Array(10,1);
 vector<double> Sum(10);  

 Sum[0] = Array[0]; 
 for(unsigned int i=1; i<Array.size(); i++)
     Sum[i] = Sum[i-1] + Array[i];
```

Is there an in-built function that will perform the above cumulative sum?

Comment: @Oded: It's most likely C++ with the std namespace included. Any Confirmation from Wawel?

Comment: @Akusete - possibly, but could be any language that supports the `<>` generic syntax and has a C like structure (Java, C#, C++...)

Comment: I agree, its far from conclusive (+1), but given the use of lowercase vector and the surrounding constructor syntax its not a bad place to start until given more info.

Comment: The tags say it's C++ ... so it's safe to say we are talking about C++

Comment: @Laurens: The C++ tag has been added by Pontus Gagge only after Akusete's comment.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Without having tested it, something like

`std::partial_sum(Array.begin(), Array.end(), Sum.begin(), plus<double>());`

should do the trick, if it's C++. (Actually, the `plus<double>()` can be defaulted out, [it seems](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/numeric/partial_sum/).)

Comment: If you want to pass the binary operation explicitly, it must be `std::plus<double>()`.

Comment: Thanks, I always misremember! Now, was that plus<double> ungood or what...? Probably summed to 1984, anyway! :-)

Comment: #include <numeric> is needed to use std::partial_sum. std::plus<double> is definitely not needed if Array is of the type std::vector<double>.